JSON input from Google-AppSheet not sending notifications to Telegram
So currently I'm in a small project to create an automatic notification in Telegram based on given input from AppSheet. I've created a bot within the AppSheet, using Webhook and applied codes within the JSON body.
Since it's new for me, I think the JSON is using JavaScript as its basic language and I've applied these lines of codes:
    {"chat_id":<TELEGRAM TOKEN ID>,
    "text":"<<CONCATENATE("Notification ",text(today()))>>\n
    <<CONCATENATE("ID: ",[ID])>>\n
   <<CONCATENATE("Registration Status: ", [Registration Status])>>\n
   <<CONCATENATE("No. of Customer: ", [CustomerNumberID])>>\n",
   "parse_mode":"MarkdownV2"}

The expected result should be, whenever a user inputs any data to [ID], [Registration Status], and [CustomerNumberID], from the Google AppSheet, it would send a notification to a Telegram channel.
The problems are:

The code won't work and no return was received on Telegram's end if I used "No. of Customer" on line 5, but it does work if I use "Number of Customer" as the return text from the corresponding input of the column's cell.
The code also doesn't work if I input numchar input on line 4, but it does work if I use whole char input. E.g.: I received a notification when I used "Ready" instead of "3-Days Offline" on the [Registration Status] input. (p.s: It ran because I replaced "No. of Customer" with "Number of Customer" on line 4.)

